# Weird behavior with GRUB when booting from Windows 10

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub

I just installed Ubuntu Budgie alongside Windows 10.

All works perfectly expect one thing: If I reboot from Ubuntu I get to the GRUB menu, that's ok. But if I am on Windows and reboot from there I get to the GRUB *prompt* and need to type "exit" to get to the GRUB menu.

I really need help on this one. I removed entries from older Linux partitions in `efibootmgr`, but nothing changed.

Comment: What brand/model system? Are both installed in UEFI boot mode? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i dunno why but disabling Fast Boot option in the bios solved the problem.

Repair-boot havent shown anything weird. So i decided to mess up a bit with bios option. A bit mysterious for me, but its working.

thx